# Error message while Writing File to azure web service

Tags: node.js, excel, azure, file, sails.js

I'm quite new to Microsoft azure, so I worked on a sails js app, I implemented a feature that allows the admin to bulk upload products in an excel file and at the server I temporary store this file on disk and then read and parse the file as .json file using npm read-excel-file and then delete the file from the filesystem. this worked perfectly in development, but when I deployed to azure using the azure app service, I'm getting this error log.

[32minfo: [39mError: Error writing file `/home/site/wwwroot/api/services/files/8900e477-683d-4f52-ac0d-9a8600ab197f.xlsx` to disk (for field `assign-users-upload`): { [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/home/site/wwwroot/api/services/files/8900e477-683d-4f52-ac0d-9a8600ab197f.xlsx']

Answer (score 1):

This can happen due to multiple reasons as below

Platform instances getting upgraded or instance(s) experiencing high latencies accessing the remote storage.

In case the instances where your application is running is experiencing high latencies accessing remote storage, platform tries to heal your application by switching to different remote storage which is having low latency.

This secondary storage have **read only permissions** on it and that is why when your application was trying to write the logs, it was failing with the access error.

**Note:**
Directly you cannot create file under `HOME`, Instead of that you can create directories. And in inside directories you can create files. This is the only files at the very root that it disallowed.

For more information Please refer this [How to deploy sail.js to azure](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails.md). & [MS Q&A](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b616878b-9dca-4db6-9900-ff74d5f3cf0f/cannot-write-to-files-anymore-from-web-app-logfiles-not-updated-anymore?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for similar query.